# I have a ansible file . I just want to run ansible file in flask API

Tags: python-2.7, flask, ansible

I have one ansible file :

```
 hosts: all
 user: vagrant
 sudo: true
 tasks:
 - user: name=pape shell=/bin/bash groups=admin append=yes
   sudo: true

 - name: Creates directory
   file: path=/home/pape/.ssh state=directory owner=pape  group=pape  
         mode=0700
   sudo: true

 - name: Make sure that the /home/{{createuser}} directory exsists
   action: file path=/home/james/.ssh state=directory

 - name: Setup | authorized key upload
   copy: src=/home/birendra/.ssh/id_rsa.pub 
    dest=/home/pape/.ssh/authorized_keys owner=pape group=pape  
    mode=0600
```

This ansible-playbook is running successfully in vagrant
   (config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10").

I want to run this file in flask API . I also have one inventory file 
   (127.0.0.1 and 192.168.33.10)

I wrote playbook ansible API

```
 playbook = PlayBook(remote_user='vagrant',      
 playbook='/home/birendra/vagrant/playbook.yml',callbacks=playbook_cb, 
 runner_callbacks=runner_cb, stats=stats, host_list=  
 '/home/birendra/birendra/inventory/swat-
 staging.ini' )
```

But it is not working

Comment: Are there any error messages / tracebacks ... At what stage does problem occure? Can't flask run the API call? How will be the playbook envoked? Did you call `the `ansible-playbook` command or did you import parts of the ansible API directly...

Comment: error message is :         GATHERING FACTS *************************************************************** 
fatal: [127.0.0.1] => SSH encountered an unknown error during the connection. We recommend etc....   ...TASK: [user name=pape shell=/bin/bash groups=admin append=yes] **************** 
FATAL: no hosts matched or all hosts have already failed -- aborting

Comment: Check if you can password free ssh to `vagrant@127.0.0.1` from the user/machine where the flask app runs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
import ansible.playbook
from ansible import callbacks
from ansible import utils
ANSIBLE_HOSTS = 'hosts'
PLAYBOOK = 'foo.yml'
def deploy():
    stats = callbacks.AggregateStats()
    playbook_cb = callbacks.PlaybookCallbacks(verbose=utils.VERBOSITY)
    inventory = ansible.inventory.Inventory(ANSIBLE_HOSTS)
    runner_cb = callbacks.PlaybookRunnerCallbacks(stats,verbose=utils.VERBOSITY)

    pb = ansible.playbook.PlayBook(playbook=PLAYBOOK,
                                   callbacks=playbook_cb,
                                   runner_callbacks=runner_cb,
                                   stats=stats, 
                                   inventory=inventory,
                                   extra_vars={'name': "AAA"})
    pb.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    deploy()
```

#### foo.yml:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  user: sergey
  sudo: no

  tasks:
    - name: Print hello
      debug: msg="Hey how are you {{ name }}"
```

#### hosts

```
[localhost]
localhost ansible_connection=local
```

#### Output:

```
PLAY [localhost] ************************************************************** 

GATHERING FACTS *************************************************************** 
ok: [localhost]

TASK: [Print hello] *********************************************************** 
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Hey how are you AAA"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. your program is running properly, but when I give vagrant.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10".   This ip I am putting in hosts file e.g [staging] 192.168.33.10 . it is giving error like     fatal: [192.168.33.10] => SSH encountered an unknown error during the connection. We recommend you re-run the ....... etc. but when I run my playbook.yml file using vagrant provsion. it is working properly.